# Click events and Keypress

Tags: events, keypress

I would like to have a button when u click on it, it would add 0.25. If I hold the ctrl button and click on the same button it will add 1 instead of 0.25. Is this possible in AngularJs?
Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**(UPDATED)**

***HTML :***

```
<input type="text" id="field" value="0" />
<input type="button" id="but" value="ADD" />
```

***JS :***

```
document.onkeydown = downkey;
document.onkeyup = upkey;
var ctrl = 0;

function downkey(e) {

    e = e || window.event;

    if (e.keyCode == '17') {
        ctrl = 0.75;
    }
}

function upkey(e) {

    e = e || window.event;

    if (e.keyCode == '17') {
        ctrl = 0;
    }
}

var clickbut =function(){
       var tmp = document.getElementById('field').value*1;
        var value =tmp+0.25+ctrl;
       document.getElementById('field').value=value;
}
```

Comment: Hello Youness, Thank you for you answer. Is there perhaps an Angular way to do this?

Comment: i understand that Angular is working with JavaScript i will update with a solution ONLY with javascript it should work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Youness I already got my answer. I used Angular Hotkeys to make this work.
For other people i'll put a link:

- http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-hotkeys/